# auto signed applet don't run

Tags: java, icedtea

I'm under Ubuntu and I have already installed icedtea.
the is the applet I'm trying to execute is auto signed.
I know that there is a security config under icedtea to prevent such applet to be run.

I'm asking where/how can I add an exception so that website will be authorized to run his applet ?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto signed"? Do you mean self-signed or something else?

Comment: yes, it's self-signed (bad translation from frensh :p)

Answer (score 0):

You must add your certificate (the one you used to sign the applet) to your keystore.

The way to do this depends on your browser and operating system, you'l need to specify these for more help.

Comment: it's a http website (not https).
and I'm under Ubuntu using the latest firefox

Comment: AFAIK, signing the applet does not depend on using http or https for the website. Could you state the exact error you get when running your applet ?

Comment: I have no error. Just the applet dont run. I got the message under Winbug and solved the issue adding the website in the java config. now I have to open Winbug every time to execute the applet :/